# Fetch active task of a person with joins

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a person table and a task table. Though a task can be done by multiple people, so in between there is a 'roster' table:

```
person
task_roster
task
```

I'm looking for a query that returns each person and their current active task. If they have no active task, it should simply return NULL. I've been messing around with the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM person
LEFT OUTER JOIN task_roster ON (task_roster.person = person.id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN task on (task.id = task_roster.task AND task.status = 1)
ORDER BY person.name
```

The problem I'm running in too is that this query returns old roster entries, so I get the same person back multiple times, for each previous task they performed. I've also tried adding a Group By on person.name, though then I don't get any of the active duties, just NULL values.

The restult I'm looking for would be like this:

```
 +----------------+-----------+----------------+
 | person.name    | task.id   | task.name      |
 +----------------+-----------+----------------+
 | David Harris   | 5         | Maintenance    |
 | Karen Simmons  | 2         | Transport      |
 | Linda Foster   | 5         | Maintenance    |
 | Michael King   | NULL      | NULL           |
 +----------------+-----------+----------------+
```

David and Linda are both working on the same task. The roster table is nothing more then a link between person.id and task.id

Comment: can you give sample records with your desired result?

Comment: We need more info:  sample data, table defs, and current (erroneous) output.. enough to start a fiddle.

Comment: Also - how do you define 'active task'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you are getting also the *old task* is because of this join statement:

```
...
task_roster ON (task_roster.person = person.id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN task
...
```

basically it displays all the records from table `task_roster`. There may be other solutions on this but my solution below uses a subquery  that gets only `person` with specific active task. The result of the subquery is then joined back on table `person` using `LEFT JOIN` so every record on table `person` will be shown on the list whether it has a matching record on the subquery or none.

```
SELECT  a.name AS PersonName,
        b.task AS TaskID,
        b.name AS TaskName
FROM    person a
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  a.person, a.task, b.name
            FROM    task_roster a
                    INNER JOIN task b
                        ON a.task = b.id
            WHERE   b.status = 1
        ) b ON  a.id = b.person
```

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if this would work:

```
SELECT person.*,task.status
FROM person
LEFT OUTER JOIN task_roster ON (task_roster.person = person.id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN task on task.id = task_roster.task
WHERE task.status=1
ORDER BY person.name
```